# SKView won't properly cast Sprite-Kit Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to transition from a ViewController to an SKScene with the code below:

```
-(void)interstitialDidDisappear:(MPInterstitialAdController *)interstitial {
    SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    GameScene *gameScene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [skView presentScene:gameScene];
}
```

I continue to get:

```
-[UIView presentScene:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I see this problem coming up a lot, but all the solutions don't seem to work for my case. I tried going into the Storyboard and changing the custom class of the View to SKView. I also tried adding it as a property and overriding the getting to return the casted view. I don't really know what to at this point, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are on the right track, but we don't have enough information to tell you where you have gone wrong. Basically self.view is a UIView, not an SKView as you already identified.   Your use of the word "transition" implies that you probably need to present a new UIViewController with an SKView in it

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you know what the problem is and even that you did the right things to fix it.

> I tried going into the Storyboard and changing the custom class of the
>   View to SKView

I am guessing you changed the wrong view in the ViewController or self.view isn't the view you want.

Without knowing anything about the structure of your game it sounds like you aren't launching it until after they view an ad which is odd. Either I am wrong or you have successfully presented your scene somewhere else in your code. I would look at what view you are grabbing there or try launching the scene on view did load.

Hopefully that helps or gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I ended up just dismissing the view controller and creating the Game back in the SKScene which the view controller was presented in. Thanks for your the feedback though